# To create a DIM table or not

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse

I have 3 fields from our transactional source table (Status, Abnormal, Type) which are all coded values. All of them do not have a code table to link to. The description for each code is only defined in their data dictionary.

I am sure that these codes are rarely moving at all.

In a scenario like this, is it still worth to create a DIM table for each field in order to have a proper FK in the Fact table?

Some thoughts Im not sure of is the added requirement to handle reloading or patching of keys when new codes become available. Any issues in just storing the actual codes in the Fact tables and have the reporting tool do the decoding of description instead

Comment: FK aside, do you want those values to be easily available to end users? Your database probably won't like `SELECT DISTINCT(Status) FROM FactTable`...

Comment: I would consider storing them in a junk dimension: https://www.kimballgroup.com/2009/06/design-tip-113-creating-using-and-maintaining-junk-dimensions/

Comment: Junk dimension was my thought also

Comment: Thanks for the insights guys appreciate it